# File_get_contents and Preg_match_all Empty Array

Tags: php

I am trying to match from a XML not hyperlinked Text and will list it hyperlinked. But it shows only as Array.. What am i doing wrong? Thanks

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://phobos.apple.com/version');
$download = preg_match_all('~(.*)/iPhone/(.*)Restore.ipsw~', $content, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
?>
```

Example Text to convert into Link
http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/061-7939.20100908.Lcyg3/iPhone3,1_4.1_8B117_Restore.ipsw

If matches should be listed like below

- http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/061-9858.20101122.Er456/iPhone3,1_4.2.1_8C148_Restore.ipsw
- http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/061-7939.20100908.Lcyg3/iPhone3,1_4.1_8B117_Restore.ipsw.
- http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/061-8619.20100715.4Pnsx/iPhone3,1_4.0.1_8A306_Restore.ipsw
- ...
- ...

Answer (score 0):

`$matches` is not an array, but an array *of arrays*, as per [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

> matches
>       Array of all matches in multi-dimensional array ordered according to flags.

The default `flags` argument is `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER`:

> Orders results so that $matches[0] is an array of full pattern
>   matches, $matches[1] is an array of strings matched by the first
>   parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

So for you `$matches[0]` is the *array* of strings that matched your regex, `$matches[1]` is the *array* of substrings corresponding to `\1`, and `$matches[2]` is the *array* of substrings corresponding to `\2`. E.g.:

```
php >print_r($matches[2]);
Array
(
    [0] => 061-4313.20080226.Sw39i/iPhone1,1_1.1.4_4A102_
    [1] => 061-4313.20080226.Sw39i/iPhone1,1_1.1.4_4A102_
    [2] => 061-4313.20080226.Sw39i/iPhone1,1_1.1.4_4A102_
    [3] => 061-4313.20080226.Sw39i/iPhone1,1_1.1.4_4A102_
     ... etc etc
)
```

So, `$matches[j][i]` refers to the *jth* capturing group of the *ith* match. (with `j=0` being the entire matching string).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.. So i code this

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://phobos.apple.com/version');

$download = preg_match_all('~(.*)/iP(.*)Restore.ipsw~', $content, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

 echo "Key: <br>"; 
 print_r($matches[0]); 
 echo "<p>URL: <br>"; 
 print_r($matches[1]);
?>
```

While i need to convert the Text to Link i coded this with some tutorial

```
<?php


    $content = file_get_contents('http://phobos.apple.com/version');

    $matches = "~(.*)/iP(.*)Restore.ipsw~";

    if(preg_match($matches, $content, $url)) {

    echo preg_replace($matches, '<a href="'.$url[0].'" rel="nofollow">'.$url[0].'</a>', $matches);

    }


?>
```

The Problem is at converting text to link that it shows only 1 hyperlink and rest will not show. http://codepad.org/v4YFfS7i